# Python how to read xlsx file and convert into csv without writing to directory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, http

I receive an `xlsx` file from an `HTTP POST` request and read it using `pd.read_excel()`. It's in unreadable binary format at first, so I convert it to `csv` using `.to_csv()`

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

response = http_post('https://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet')
xlsx = pd.read_excel(response.content)
xlsx.to_csv('outputname.csv', index=False)
```

This works, it gives me a readable version of the data, but the problem is `to_csv()` is also writing the file to my directory, and I don't want to save this data anywhere. I just want to get the file content using http, convert it to csv, work with that data in my script, then have it vanish once I no longer need it; no writing to other files.

Is there a way to do this? Do I even need to be converting to `csv` to get a readable representation of the `xlsx` data?

Comment: You don't need to call .to_csv(). Just operate on your data frame you got from .read_excel()

Comment: You seem to be confusing "CSV" and "data". You already have the data in memory. If you don't want to write it to a file, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is a file format; there is no particular reason to want CSV in memory, except perhaps if you will eventually write it to disk but need to preprocess the bytes somehow before that. Simply reading the data into a Pandas data frame is almost certainly all you want or need here.

Comment: If the data in `xslx` is not directly usable to you, perhaps (accept this and) ask a new question with a sample of the problematic data

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 

response = http_post('https://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet')
xlsx = pd.read_excel(response.content) 
xlsx = xlsx.csv('outputname.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.